# why wordpress has impressive SEO result on google

Tags: html, wordpress, seo

I design website as most SEO rules such as important tags(h1, h2, article, strong, ...), schema.org, html5, metakeys, description , etc..

When I design a website with wordpress with same content via cheep rules of SEO, wordpress come with impressive result in google search.But my regular website has week result.

Then I think wordpress has some cheat in backend or main structure.

what`s happen??

Comment: This is off-topic for this website. Wordpress isn't special in any way. It is very search engine friendly out of the box which helps but it has no advantages over a non-wordpress site nor does it use any black hat techniques. The odds are your non-wordpress sites are poorly structured.

Comment: Do you validate (http://validator.w3.org) your code for your non WP sites? This is important too for SEO.

Comment: I have a same problem. search this 'نباید منتظر کاهش قیمت رسمی خودرو باشیم' on google. take a loop on result www.momtaznews.com

my site is google result `نباید منتظر کاهش قیمت رسمی خودرو باشیم site:parsnews.com`